# Imports with NoseXUnit

Tags: nose

I am testing NoseXUnit to see if I can get XML & coverage information from some code.  I have found that if I import my code under test using

```
from testme import testmefunction
```

Nose crashes giving the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/opt/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nose/util.py", line 622, in newfunc
    return func(*arg, **kw)
TypeError: testmefunction() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

This message comes up even if I just have the import statement and do not use the testmefunction() at all.  I tried googling an answer and poking around the code and I do not see anything wrong.  I can successfully import using:

```
import testme
```

then using testme.testmefunction()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to my question:

https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/issues/127

Renamed everything from test to try and it worked.